# too many xruns in jack

Tags: sound, jack

I'm getting a lot of xruns in jack--about one every .5 seconds. I have been told that this is a very computer specific problem that could have a lot of causes. Is there anyone here who could advise me on this?

When I start jack from terminal, nothing too startling comes up. But there might be some other diagnostic that someone can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://wiki.linuxmusicians.com/doku.php?id=system_configuration
First thing I would check is CPU frequency scaling. Try to disable that and see if that yields any improvement.

Regards,

Jeremy